# Ubuntu 14.10 Startup & Shutdown Issues w/ HP Pavilion x360

Tags: boot, 14.10, shutdown, startup

I have an HP Pavilion x360 n010dx running Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn with the Linux kernel "linux-signed-image-3.16.0-23-generic", and I am having issues with Ubuntu starting up as well as with Ubuntu turning itself off.

The first time I turn the computer on from its completely shut off state, and after I input my disk encryption password, the computer will hang at the crypt_swap being successfully set up message.  I then have to hold down the power button to force the computer to turn off.  However, when I try to start up the computer *again*, it will get past the crypt_swap message, check the disk for errors and start up perfectly fine.  It seems to work *every other time.*

When it comes to turning the computer off, Ubuntu itself can't seem to make the computer do so.  When I tell the computer to shut down through Ubuntu, it will transition to the purple Ubuntu splash screen and freeze there after a couple of seconds.  The only way for me to actually turn the computer off is to once again hold down the power button.

I read on another forum (I can't find the link right now...) that it could be a module called "hp_accel" that is causing the startup problem.  I believe this *may* be it, because I started Ubuntu through Recovery Mode in GRUB, and the last message to appear had something to do with hp_accel reverting to default configuration since it couldn't identify my laptop before the startup process froze up as usual.  Concerning the shutdown issue, I have no idea what could be causing that.

So, what can I do to fix these issues, if anything?  Should I provide some sort of log to help diagnose the problem?  If so, what log would I want to get and how do I get it (never dealt with logs and log-fetching before so I have no idea what to do when it comes to that)?

Thanks!

SIDE NOTE: I know that the latest Linux kernel image I can get through the Ubuntu Software Update program is 3.16.0-29, but with that image, my computer would freeze on startup *100% of the time.*  So, I reverted back to the -23 image because I could at least get it to start some of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 Alpha 2 solves most of the problems. My computer fails to load when I let it start with no intervention. If I stroke an arrow key and select Ubuntu (even if it's the only OS), the computer loads.

The shut down seems to be fixed with this.

```
echo "blacklist dw_dmac" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist dw_dmac_core" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

By the way, Ubuntu 15.04 is really stable in my PC, only one reboot in two weeks, even with Alpha 1. So, more stable than Windows 8.1.

Comment: I am in the process of downloading Ubuntu 15.04 nightly to install.  Would you recommend that I do an upgrade, or should I just wipe everything and do a fresh install?  Also, can you please tell me what those commands you posted actually do and what they change?  I just put them in now and will do a test shutdown and see if the issue is fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: Just an update: Those commands above didn't fix the shutdown issue.  I will just do a clean install of the latest 15.04 daily build, and then I will put the commands above in and see if they fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but those commands do in fact fix the shutdown issue, and I believe they have helped with the startup one as well.

Comment: This fixed my issues random freeze and shutdown. How could you know that it was this mods that was causing the issue, and what are these mods for?