# dual-boot : Ubuntu / Windows 10 on Hp pavilion x360

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hp

yesterday I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my HP pavilion x360

I followed [Ubuntu 14.10 Startup & Shutdown Issues w/ HP Pavilion x360](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580666/ubuntu-14-10-startup-shutdown-issues-w-hp-pavilion-x360) and solved my shutdown/restart issue

I tried this [No wireless connection on HP Pavilion x360 Convertible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677621/no-wireless-connection-on-hp-pavilion-x360-convertible) to solve my wifi issue, but it didn't work (I still can't access wifi)

This morning come a new issue far more problematic : I can't access my grub anymore.

When I boot this morning, I chose windows because I have no connection on Ubuntu (I had the grub at that time), later, I tried to reboot on ubuntu : and my grub is gone, I have absolutely no way of starting Ubuntu.

I've seen a few things in the comments here https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/130-distributions/839692-dual-boot-ubuntu-15041410-and-windows-10818-step-by-step-tutorial-with-screenshots

but nothing worked for me so far

I suppose windows have done something but can't figure out what

Comment: Have you tried [looking here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205)?  Please edit your question with this new information and leave a comment.

Comment: i'm still trying to find the answer to the wifi problem, but i also have a x360 and the grub doesn't appear at startup, but if i hit f9, while it's starting up, it works and i can go in to Ubuntu.
i know you posted this question like 6 months ago, so you've probably figured it out by now, but for anyone else who reads this who might have the same problem... there ya go :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I know you can do that know, but it is a bit annoying. In the end, my girlfriend (for whom the laptop was) just gave up on linux, and stayed with windows. If you want to add an official answer, I'll gladly validate it

Comment: See if these help: HP Check if Customized UEFI settings available like this  HP ProBook 4340
http://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file
And: http://askubuntu.com/questions/346257/install-alongside-windows-8-is-not-working AND: Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 or:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Comment: thank you oldfred, sadly the laptop owner gave up and got rid of ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a HP pavillion x360 11k001nl. I managed to prepare a usb live key with ubuntu 14.04 64bit which does everything but recognizing the partitions (ubuntu installer says that the partitions are "hidden" and sees only that of the usb key I don't know how to make them visible as well as usable by ubuntu installer). Anyway I followed this advice:

to activate wifi negli x360

from terminal:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "11n_disable=1"
```

Then reboot.

---

to remove the block of the shutdown of the system
from terminal as root (of course):

```
echo "blacklist dw_dmac" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist dw_dmac_core" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

---

If Acer

```
rfkill list all
```

I don't run Ubuntu (Fedora) but had the same problem (wifi not switching on) on an HP PAV x360 and also had the same symptoms, namely:

```
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
```

You need to blacklist the acer_wmi module (it never should have been loaded!)

```
lsmod | grep acer
```

Edit (or create if it doesn't exist) `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Add the following lines

```
# Disable acer_wmi as it breaks wifi on this model
blacklist acer_wmi
```

Now unload the module (it will be blacklisted on the next boot so you only need to unload once)

```
 modprobe -r acer_wmi
```

Enjoy your working wifi!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The person using the laptop gave up and the ubuntu partition was removed. I hope this will help some other user :-)